# awk to capture and reformat based on pattern

Tags: awk

The `awk` below captures the desired output for lines 1-5 in the `input` below. I am struggling with the sixth line and can not seem to add a portion to the `awk` to capture and print line 6 as in the desired output. Printing the `id` as well as portion after the `-`. I have tried adding a split but the prints only numbers in field 5. I apologize for the long post just trying to include the details as I can not seem to figure this out. Thank you :)

**spilt tried**

```
{ 
  split($4,F,/_/)
   if(split($4,A,/[_]/)) {
    if(A[2]~/[[:alpha:]]/)
     p=A[2]
}
 }
{
print "chr" $1, $2, $3, "chr" $1 ":" $2 "-" $3 OFS p
}
```

**input**  `tab-delimeted`

```
6   18122723    18122843    469_380805_378884(NHLRC1)_1.1_1
6   31114121    31114241    344047_16724314_rs746647_1
6   31430946    31431066    344049_16724385_HCP5(10866)_1_1
6   32808479    32808599    445446_18754304_PSMB8-exon6_1
1   33478785    33478905    19186497_AK2-Exon1_1
1   24022788    24022908    466743_18956150_RPL11-NM_000975-exon6_1
```

**desired output**  `tab-delimeted`

```
chr6    18122723    18122843    chr6:18122723-18122843  NHLRC1
chr6    31114121    31114241    chr6:31114121-31114241  rs746647
chr6    31430946    31431066    chr6:31430946-31431066  HCP5
chr6    32808479    32808599    chr6:32808479-32808599  PSMB8-exon6
chr1    33478785    33478905    chr1:33478785-33478905  AK2-Exon1
chr1    24022788    24022908    chr1:24022788-24022908  RPL11-exon6
```

**awk**

```
awk '
 {
  split($4,F,/_/)
   if(split(F[3],G,/[)(]/)) {
     if(G[2]~/[[:alpha:]]/)
     p=G[2]
   else 
     p=G[1]
} 
   else 
     p=F[3]
}
{ 
  split($4,F,/_/)
   if(split($4,A,/[_]/)) {
    if(A[2]~/[[:alpha:]]/)
     p=A[2]
}
 }
{
print "chr" $1, $2, $3, "chr" $1 ":" $2 "-" $3 OFS p
}
' FS='\t' OFS='\t' input
```

**current output**  `tab-delimeted`

```
chr6    18122723    18122843    chr6:18122723-18122843  NHLRC1
chr6    31114121    31114241    chr6:31114121-31114241  rs746647
chr6    31430946    31431066    chr6:31430946-31431066  HCP5
chr6    32808479    32808599    chr6:32808479-32808599  PSMB8-exon6
chr1    33478785    33478905    chr1:33478785-33478905  AK2-Exon1
chr1    24022788    24022908    chr1:24022788-24022908  RPL11-NM
```

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a rule defined to reject `NM` token.  It has alpha char How do you describe it to someone if this is done manually?  For example why accept RPL11 but reject NM_000975

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is another approach

```
$ awk 'BEGIN (FS=OFS="\t"} 
             {n=split($NF,a,"[_()-]"); 
              key=sep=""; 
              for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if(a[i]~/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/) 
                 {key=key sep a[i]; sep="-"} 
              print $1,$2,$3,"chr"$1":"$2"-"$3,key }' file


6  18122723  18122843  chr6:18122723-18122843  NHLRC1
6  31114121  31114241  chr6:31114121-31114241  rs746647
6  31430946  31431066  chr6:31430946-31431066  HCP5
6  32808479  32808599  chr6:32808479-32808599  PSMB8-exon6
1  33478785  33478905  chr1:33478785-33478905  AK2-Exon1
1  24022788  24022908  chr1:24022788-24022908  RPL11-exon6
```

Answer (score 2):

Your shown output's last line doesn't seems to be matching your law(which is applied to all other lines), considering that this is a typo, try following.

```
awk '
{
  if($NF ~ /\(/){
    sub(/.*\(/,"",$NF);
    sub(/\).*/,"",$NF)}
  else          {
    num=split($NF,array,"_");
    $NF=array[num-1]}
}
{
  $NF=$1":"$2"-"$3 OFS $NF
}
1
'   Input_file
```